# What is name of this component

Tags: c#, winforms, components

Please say name of this component and does c# have it?

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, what script / language is that?

Comment: Are you asking about the accordion or the thing that the arrow is pointing to in a list that I can't read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have suggested, this is commonly called an **Outlook Bar** after it's most famous usage in the Microsoft Outlook application.

Something similar is available in most third-party control suites, but if you're looking for something that is free and easily customizable, you might check out the **[OutlookBar](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/menus/OutlookBar.aspx)** control available on CodeProject:

[image: OutlookBar sample]

The control itself is pretty simple, and implemented entirely in managed C# code as a `UserControl`.
It should work under all versions of the .NET Framework back to 1.1, and is painless to integrate into your application. Best of all, with the source code freely downloadable, it's infinitely customizable to fit your specific needs!

Answer (score 3):

I think it is called accordion, at least in jQuery.

And I do not know of any such in the basic controlles that comes with c# but I am cetrain that there are many 3:rd party components like this.

[ComponentArts](http://www.componentart.com//) or [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) are the first that comes to mind.

Comment: Thanks but i dont like 3rd party components. Does visual studio c# have something like this ? three view is bad for this yea?

Comment: Tou could code your own component for it if you realy do not like 3:rd party.

Comment: I believe it's called a PanelBar in Telerik

Answer (score 2):

In WinForms, this is called an Outlook Bar or Navigation bar.
Most (if not all) third-party control suites, such as [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Navbar/), offer it.

Answer (score 1):

I think its name is `Accordion` and it doesn't exists natively on Windows Forms Architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Accordion ? Try searching among different control toolkits - there should be an implementation.